# Miles Reid Commutative Algebra exercise 3.3 (Noetherian rings)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

I would like how could one prove the following

> Let $R$ be a ring, $\mathfrak{a}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{a}_r$ ideals of $R$ such that each $R/\mathfrak{a}_i$ is a Noetherian ring. Then
>
> 1. $\bigoplus_{i=1}^rR/\mathfrak{a}_i$ is a Noetherian $R$-module
> 2. If $\bigcap_{i=1}^r\mathfrak{a}_i=0$, then $R$ is a Noetherian ring

This is proved in [*A Term of Commutative Algebra*](https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/arithmetic_geometry/teaching/exercises/Altman_-Kleiman---A-term-of-commutative-algebra-_2017_.pdf), page 325 of the text, 16.36. These are some free lecture notes by Allen Altman and Steven Kleiman which I am studying from, however, I find their answer rather unsatisfactory, because I can't justify most of the things they assume to be true. Is there another way to prove the aforementioned facts?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you give examples of steps you can’t justify?

Comment: For example, the whole proof of $1$: "Since $R/a_i$ is a Noetherian ring, such an ideal is finitely generated as an $(R/a_i)$- module, *so as an $R$-module as well*". Why?

Comment: 1: because the $R/\mathfrak{a}_i$ are Noetherian. 2, Since then $R$ injects into the direct sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring and $I$ an ideal thereof. Let $S=R/I$, for simplicity.

Then every $S$-module $M$ becomes an $R$-module, by defining $rx=(r+I)x$. The verification is easy. The set of $R$-submodules of $M$ is the same as the set of $S$-submodules of $M$. Thus, if $M$ is Noetherian as an $S$-module, it is also as an $R$-module.

In your case, each $R/\mathfrak{a}_i$ is Noetherian as a ring, so also as a module over $R/\mathfrak{a}_i$, hence also as a module over $R$.

Finally, use that $R/\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{a}_i$ embeds as an $R$-module in the direct sum $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n R/\mathfrak{a}_i$.